# How to do a 1 to many using LINQ and EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

In my *Place Repository* I want to bring all the `Place` records including any `Registration` records for each `Place`, even if there are no records in the `Registration` table.

Currently I have:

```
public IEnumerable<Place> Places
{
   get
   {
      return _appDbContext.Places.Include(r => r.Registrations.Where(q => q.PlaceId == r.Id));
   }
}
```

Results in the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Where(r => EF.Property(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Place ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer IsNullable: False , "Id") != null && object.Equals( objA: (object)EF.Property(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Place ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer IsNullable: False , "Id"), objB: (object)EF.Property(r, "PlaceId"))) .Where(r => r.PlaceId == r.Id)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The Model:

```
public class Place
{
   private const int _annualFiguresDueWithinDays = 90;
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter in the Place's name.")]
   [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length for the place name is 100 characters.")]
   public string PlaceName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}

public class Registration
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("PlaceId")]
   public int PlaceId { get; set; }
   public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }
   public bool IsFirstRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Include(r => r.Registrations)` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the include function to this

```
public IEnumerable<Place> Places
{
   get
   {
      return _appDbContext.Places.Include(r => r.Registrations));
   }
}
```

Comment: EF will generate the correct SQL join filter constraints from the navigation property configuration.